I've some trouble studing python flet. Is it bug or my fault?
Please help me find the reason for this code behavior
There are 3 identical boxes (flet Container()) with switch (flet Switch()).
Only switch in first box "unit_view1" is available for switching. Other two are not.
Why ???
I can't find any reason that interferes with the behavior of the switches
import flet as ft


def _name_row(unit_name):
    return ft.Container(alignment=ft.alignment.center, content=ft.Text(value=unit_name, size=36))


def set_on_off(value):
    print("unit is", "on" if value else "off")


class Unit(ft.UserControl):
    def __init__(self, unit_name: str):
        super().__init__()
        self.unit_name = unit_name

    def build(self):
        _cnt = ft.Container(
            padding=10,
            width=250,
            border=ft.border.all(3),
            border_radius=30,
            content=ft.Column(
                controls=[
                    ft.Switch(
                        label="Вкл",
                        active_color="green",
                        on_change=set_on_off

                    ),
                    ft.Divider(),
                    _name_row(self.unit_name),
                    ft.Divider(),
                ]
            )
        )
        return _cnt


class UnitsView(ft.UserControl):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.unit_view1 = Unit(unit_name="Unit 1")
        self.unit_view2 = Unit(unit_name="Unit 2")
        self.unit_view3 = Unit(unit_name="Unit 3")

    def build(self):
        _cnt = ft.Container(
            alignment=ft.alignment.center,
            padding=50,
            width=400,
            content=ft.Row(
                spacing=10,
                controls=[
                    self.unit_view1,
                    ft.VerticalDivider(),
                    self.unit_view2,
                    ft.VerticalDivider(),
                    self.unit_view3,
                ],
            ),
        )
        return _cnt


def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.window_width = 960
    page.window_height = 300

    page.add(UnitsView())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ft.app(target=main)


View of app
I tested a similar one without classes, I only use simple Flet controls it and it works there.

What exactly does that mean, “Only first switch is available for switching”?

Only the switch in the first box is toggled. In the rest - no

I'm new to flet so I can't explain it, but it can be accomplished by creating an instance of the switch as a class and arranging it in a row. I'm optimizing the messages I get by adding that and the status of the switch's behavior. I have also changed the class to a method of the switch behavior.
import flet as ft

def _name_row(unit_name):
    return ft.Container(alignment=ft.alignment.center, content=ft.Text(value=unit_name, size=36))


class Unit(ft.UserControl):
    def __init__(self, unit_name: str):
        super().__init__()
        self.unit_name = unit_name
        self.status = False

    def set_on_off(self,e):
        self.status = not self.status
        print(self.unit_name, "on" if self.status else "off")

    def build(self):
        switch = ft.Container(
            padding=10,
            width=250,
            border=ft.border.all(3),
            border_radius=30,
            content=ft.Column(
                controls=[
                    ft.Switch(
                        label="Вкл",
                        active_color="green",
                        on_change=self.set_on_off

                    ),
                    ft.Divider(),
                    _name_row(self.unit_name),
                    ft.Divider(),
                ]
            )
        )
        return switch

def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.window_width = 960
    page.window_height = 300

    unit_view1 = Unit(unit_name="Unit 1")
    unit_view2 = Unit(unit_name="Unit 2")
    unit_view3 = Unit(unit_name="Unit 3")
    page.add(ft.Row([unit_view1, unit_view2, unit_view3]))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ft.app(target=main)


Thanks
Yes, I did it the same way. But I wanted to understand the reason why it doesn’t work when placing Unit inside another container UnitsView.
When these objects were in a Row(),
such as
page.add(ft.Row([unit_view1, unit_view2, unit_view3]))
everything worked.

The issue is resolved by removing the width from the UnitsView control.  It is moving the hit click detection beyond the rendered size of the control and never "sees" the click.
